# php filter with get variables

Tags: php, variables, filter, get

I suck at regexp but i'd like to just do a simple filter where / is replaced with 1, " is replaced with 2 and < is replaced with 3.
I'd appreciate an example where the syntax would be straight forward, i'd like to run this filter through the input of a get variable provided by the user. A syntax like:

```
replace(/,1)
replace(",2)
replace(<,3)
```

.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried researching any of this?

Comment: `strtr` would be more appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't see the need for regex here.. You can just use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

E.g.

```
str_replace('/', '1', $_GET['var']);
```